# How to overcome Memory error when reading large file (over 1GB) -- C/C++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I am trying to read a file of over 1GB (which has 1,157,421,364 bytes), it gives memory error when using fread() function, but works well when I use fgets() function.
Note: I have intermixed C and C++..

Can someone help me to overcome this memory error, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance...

**Error is "Memory Error"**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

void read_file2(FILE* readFilePtr){
    long file_size;

    fseek(readFilePtr, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(readFilePtr);
    rewind(readFilePtr);

    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*file_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fputs("Memory Error", stderr);
        exit(2);
    }
    long lines = 0;
    if (fread(buffer, 1, file_size, readFilePtr) != file_size){
        fputs("Reading Error", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *p = buffer;
    while (p = (char*) memchr(p, '\n', (buffer + file_size) - p)){
        ++p;
        ++lines;
    }
    printf("Num of lines %ld\n", lines);
    free(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    clock_t begin_time, end_time;
    float time_consumed;

    begin_time = clock();

    FILE* inputFilePtr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(inputFilePtr == NULL){
        printf("Error Opening %s: %s (%u)\n", argv[1], strerror(errno), errno);
        return 1;
    }

    read_file2(inputFilePtr);

    end_time = clock();

    time_consumed = ((float)end_time - (float)begin_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time consumed is -- %f\n", time_consumed);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: updated... It is giving "memory error"

Comment: no, we need the exact message of the error. But actually this is almost obvious enough to not need the error, so try some of the solution below.

Comment: It is giving "Segmentation fault"

Comment: Granted that it's not the 1980s anymore and we usually have many gigabytes to play with (embedded stuff excepted), I still would advise against having one process use an entire gigabyte+ unless there's absolutely no way around it. It has to share resources with everything else on the system, for one thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the file in chunks, instead of reading it as a whole, reading all of the file to one allocated buffer means a huge memory allocation of your application, do you really want that?. That's being said assuming you don't need to process it all in once (which is true in most cases).

Comment: And it seems to be true in this case, which is counting newlines. +1

Comment: I agree that I can read in chunks for my use, is there any way I can read all at once? is it directly depending on my System memory?

Comment: Not directly. it is also dependent on your OS, and how much memory it allocates for each process. If all you do is counting lines, you don't really need to store the file in your application memory.

Comment: @Ringo: its depending on memory fragmentation. after a long system run the memory will be fragmented and you cant fit 1gb thing in there. but right after start up everything will be in one chunk and there will be place for 1gb.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't read big files in one go like that. You use something called buffered reads. Essentially you continuously call `fread` in a loop until there's nothing left to read.